# Simplify the following compound fraction:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{2x+1}{\frac{3}{x^2}+\frac{2x+1}{x}}$$

My calculator says the final answer is $$\frac{x^2(2x+1)}{2x^2+x+3}$$

Please show the work. Thanks.

Comment: I did it with my dad and got it down to that but I am unsure if that is fully simplified.

Comment: It cannot be simplified any further. The calculator result is correct. If you got it to that point, well done. You've already solved it.

Comment: You could simplify it a bit more as the numerator has a higher degree than the denominator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First recall that
\[ \frac{a}{b} \pm \frac{c}{d} =\frac{ad \pm cb}{bd} \]
And 
\[ \frac{a}{\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)} =\frac{ad}{c} \]
Then
\[
\frac{2x+1}{\frac{3}{x^{2}}+\frac{2x+1}{x}}= \frac{2x+1}{\frac{3x+x^{2}(2x+1)}{x^{3}}}= \frac{x^{3}(2x+1)}{3x+x^{2}(2x+1)}= \frac{x^{3}(2x+1)}{2x^{3}+x^{2}+3x}= \frac{x^{3}(2x+1)}{x(2x^{2}+x+3)}= \frac{x^{2}(2x+1)}{2x^{2}+x+3}
\]

Answer (score 2):

You multiply at the numerator and at the denominator by $x^2$:

$$\frac{2x+1}{\frac{3}{x^2}+\frac{2x+1}{x}}=\frac{x^2(2x+1)}{x^2 \left ( \frac{3}{x^2}+\frac{2x+1}{x}\right)}=\frac{x^2(2x+1)}{3+x(2x+1)}=\frac{x^2(2x+1)}{2x^2+x+3}$$

Answer (score 1):

First let's start with your denominator, $$\frac{3}{x^2}+\frac{2x+1}{x}$$
We can turn this into one term by multiplying the,
 $$\frac{2x+1}{x} by \frac{x}{x}$$

and then combine terms to get, 
$$\frac{2x^2+x+3}{x^2}$$

Now if we put this back into the first expression we now have,
$$\frac{2x+1}{\frac{2x^2+x+3}{x^2}}$$

From here we simply need to multiply the numerator and denominator by x^2 and we get,
$$\frac{x^2(2x+1)}{2x^2+x+3}$$

Hope this helps!

Comment: Check out [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your answers prettier

Comment: Excellent, thank you DanZimm!

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be considered complete, but, as I said in my comments above, you could simplify a bit more since the numerator has a higher degree than the denominator, i.e.:$$
\frac{x^2(2x+1)}{2x^2+x+3}=\frac{2x^3+x^2}{2x^2+x+3}=\frac{2x^3+x^2+3x-3x}{2x^2+x+3}
$$$$=\frac{x(2x^2+x+3)-3x}{2x^2+x+3}=x-\frac{3x}{2x^2+x+3}$$

Comment: However, it is questionable whether this is any simpler